# Header not expanding when clicking navbar button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a collapsible bootstrap navigation. I made a few changes to a .css so that navigation links look like tabs. Positioning links at the bottom of header using a margin property did not work, because when zooming in and out navigation was sometimes pushed up or down by a pixel. Instead I set a position property to absolute to place navigation at the bottom of the hader. Now when I click on the navbar button. Navigation is pushed upwards instead of downwards and header is not expanding.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="header-inner clearfix">
    <nav class="navigation pull-right" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: auto;">
            <ul class="nav menu nav-pills">
                <li>
                    <a>link1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>link2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a>link3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
    border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-color: #cc0000;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 8px 12px 8px 12px;
}

.header-inner {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cc0000;
    position: relative
}

.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Im hoping this can be solved setting a margin of navigation using different units than pixels if not, how can I change the .js file.

Comment: can't understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Could you possibly chuck this into codepen with all the other resources you are loading so I can play around?

Comment: please provide a working snippet

Comment: CSS 101: Absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal layout flow, so that it can not influence the height of its ancestor any more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I already solved a problem. When a screen width is smaller than 900 px, when instead of navigation bar a navigation button apears I just set a position property to static and now everithing works fine.
Thanks anyway